# Which kana/kanji are used to write Yoshitoshi's death poem?

Tags: kanji, kana, quotes

Browsing for art late at night, I came across this beautiful poem by [Yoshitoshi](http://www.yoshitoshi.net/), said to be his death poem:

> yo o tsumete
>
> terimasarishi wa
>
> natsu no tsuki

translated as:

holding back the night / with its increasing brilliance / the summer moon

...which I'd like to be able to write. How is this written? Which kana and kanji are used?

Comment: Wow, I was looking up this guy to see if I could find an answer for you, and his work is just beautiful! I've only really ever looked into Hokusai's work for class...shame on me, I know ;)

Comment: i've never liked hokusai. but hiroshige's colors are nice. no one's got that rough-and-ready-to-draw-thing like yoshitoshi though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was originally a comment to point out that it may not have been written with the kana/kanji in use today, but I realized it's an example of an alternative way to write it:
[image]

It's a painting of Yoshitoshi that was published by another artist in the same month he died.

The [source](http://metro2.tokyo.opac.jp/tml/tpic/cgi-bin/detail.cgi?Kbseqid=858&orgkbseqid=&Sryparam=001&Backpage=/tml/tpic/resprint_d/all/isbn001_0_30/isbn001_001_395.html&Srhfname=/resprint_d/all/isbn001_0_30/isbn001&Rp_kind=8&Displmt=30&Backpage2=&Srhfname2=&Cpage=&Size=&bSize=&Dstate=) transcribes it the same way it's written in silvermaples answer.

Comment: it's so funny how the の in the calligraphy above gets un-grass-scriptified and un-hiraganafied into 乃

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

> 夜{よ}をつめて照{てり}まさりしか夏{なつ}の月{なつ}

I found it [here](http://www.tmtkknst.com/journals/bn2009_08.html) (near the bottom), and it seems to have "ka" where what you found says "wa"...I've found other romaji versions with "wa", so I'm not sure which is correct...